# Servlet redirecting to blank page

Tags: java, redirect, servlets

Whenever i click on `submit` it redirects to a blank page but the url works fine 
im confused on whether my response tag is wrong

**Code:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {             
    Connection con=connector.getConnection();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");  
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String message = null;
    String url = null;
   try { 
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( "Select * from data Where username=?'" + username + "' and password=?'" + password + "';");
        ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("username"));
        ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("password"));
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
               if(rs.next()) {
               RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("practice1.jsp");
               rd.forward(request,response);

               }
               else {
               message="Invalid Input Please Try Again";
             request.setAttribute("message", message);
             request.setAttribute("url", url);

           }
   }


   catch(SQLException ex){
    message="ERROR"+ex.getMessage();
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please let me know What i am missing.

Comment: You are not forwarding your request anywhere if the code executes the `else` statement. That would give you a blank page.

Comment: i even tried using while and erasing if else

Comment: The query does not seem correct. I don't think you meant to pass the values of the _username_ and _password_ in the prepared statement query string; you just need to set the parameters (as you do right after). Given this, I believe that your code throws an exception, which is caught in the _catch_ clause, meaning that you are not redirecting. Check your log files for the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix it, by changing below code:

**Before:**

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( "Select * from data Where username=?'" + username + "' and password=?'" + password + "';");
ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("username"));
ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("password"));
```

**After:**

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( "Select * from data Where username=? and password=?");
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the if block whenever there are data the request dispatcher will forward the request to  practice1.jsp page.

```
if(rs.next()) {
               RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("practice1.jsp");
               rd.forward(request,response);
               }
```

But in case of else block only request are being set as follows:

```
request.setAttribute("message", message);
request.setAttribute("url", url);
```

But we should specify the response not request if we want to display in UI.

```
else {
         message="Invalid Input Please Try Again";
         response.getWriter().print("<html><head><title>
                                 Oops an error happened!</title> </head>");
         response.getWriter().print("<body>"+message+"</body>");
         response.getWriter().println("</html>");
         //request.setAttribute("message", message);
         //request.setAttribute("url", url);

         }
```